# combine queries as one query for optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have written the following queries where I am updating two tables but do so in three different queries

Conditions with queries are as follows:

Check the empty seat from table which is against "user_id" and update "user_id" to set the seat

```
UPDATE seats SET user_id = '101', modified = NOW() WHERE  book_id ='123' AND user_id = '0' LIMIT 1
```

Once `seat` is set update `book` table for updating time against `book id`

```
UPDATE books SET end_time = '$end_time', modified = NOW() WHERE  id ='123';
```

Again update `seats` table for updating `registered` column to 1, in `seat` table with same `book_id`

```
UPDATE seats SET registered = '1', modified = NOW() WHERE  book_id ='123';
```

Can I write them as one optimized query?

Answer (score 1):

You can join those tables and do all the updates in one statement, but not, if you really want to update just one row. As you can see in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) only the single table syntax supports `LIMIT`.

```
Single-table syntax:

UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]

Multiple-table syntax:

UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

If you want to combine those queries in one statement, because you fear about race conditions, have a look at transactions. Do it like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE seats SET user_id = '101', modified = NOW() WHERE  book_id ='123' AND user_id = '0' LIMIT 1;
UPDATE books SET end_time = '$end_time', modified = NOW() WHERE  id ='123';
UPDATE seats SET registered = '1', modified = NOW() WHERE  book_id ='123';
COMMIT;
```

This ensures, that either all statements in this block succeed or none. If the last one fails the previous ones do get rollbacked. They are treated like one statement, read more about this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). Prerequisite is, that you use a storage engine capable of transactions, like InnoDB. Also make sure, that you use an appropriate [isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_level).